# Using applyOptional in Monocle

Tags: monocle-scala

I'm trying to figure out how to use applyOptional. I've got this:

```
import monocle.function.all.index
import monocle.macros.{GenLens, Lenses}
import monocle.std.map._
import monocle.syntax.ApplyOptionalOps._
import monocle.function.Index._

val map: Map[Int, String] = Map.empty
val lens = map applyOptional index(4)
```

But the compiler tells me "Cannot resolve symbol applyOptional." I imported ApplyOptionalOps._ just to confirm that I had the right imports.

Answer (score 0):

`ApplyOptionalOps` is the case class with the source object as the parameter, so by importing its companion object one can't access its functions. One should `import monocle.syntax.apply._` instead, which extends `ApplySyntax` trait containing implicit conversion from generic source object to `ApplyOptionalOps` as well as some other operation wrappers. In fact, for just this example it the following imports is sufficient:

```
import monocle.syntax.apply._
import monocle.function.Index._

val map: Map[Int, String] = Map.empty
val lens = map applyOptional index(4)
```

Comment: I've a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47786656/839733) regarding `composeOptional` that I've not received any answer to. Would you mind taking a look?